# How to create newlines?

Tags: line-breaking, matrices, arrays

I am new to Latex and found out how to use it a bit. Newlines are created by `\\`

I get the following error:
`\\ can only appear in a matrix or array`

How do you create newlines between matrix or arrays?

Thanks

EDIT: Here's the code. This is for an online forum that processes LaTeX.

```
a = 
\left[
\begin {array}{ccc}
1& 2&3\\
\noalign{\medskip}
4&5&6
\end {array}
\right]

b = a .+ 1 

b = 
\left[
\begin {array}{ccc}
2&3&4\\
\noalign{\medskip}
5&6&7
\end {array}
\right]
```

By the way, what is the proper etiquette to post the code? Do I need code tags? Or LaTeX tags?  Thanks.

Comment: Would you please show an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in @Alan's edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You can format code by selecting the text and clicking on the `{}` icon. It's also helpful to post complete [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I didn't know if I should also show it as formatted in LaTeX. How would you do that? I checked the FAQ but I didn't see anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the **amsmath** package (`\usepackage{amsmath}`); then

```
\begin{align*}
a &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 2&3\\
4&5&6
\end{bmatrix}
\\
b &= a \mathbin{.+} 1 
\\
b &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
2&3&4\\
5&6&7
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

will print the three formulas in different lines.

The code `\noalign{\medskip}` works, but it's more practical to write

```
\\[\medskipamount]
```

instead of

```
\\
\noalign{\medskip}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the full details of the forum that you're posting on, it's hard to be 100% sure.

However, it appears that you have not told the forum to process your code in Math Mode.

There are a variety of ways that you can enter Math Mode, including

- `$...$`
- `\[ ... \]`
- `\( ... \)`
- `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`

but the forum you mention may not support all of these. Presumably it will support at least the first two.

A good approach might be to compile your code locally before posting to the forum to make sure that you know what you want it look like- this will help you to narrow down if it's the forum that is not processing your code correctly, or if you have incorrect code. A MWE example follows of what your code might look like in a document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ll}
    a & = \left[
            \begin {array}{ccc}
            1& 2&3\\
            \noalign{\medskip}
            4&5&6
            \end {array}
        \right]\\
            \noalign{\medskip}
    b & = a .+ 1 \\
            \noalign{\medskip}
     & = 
        \left[
            \begin {array}{ccc}
            2&3&4\\
            \noalign{\medskip}
            5&6&7
            \end {array}
        \right]
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the $$ or <math> tags.